# C++ Type error with Object versus Object reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, pass-by-reference

I have the following function (which worked in Visual Studio):

```
bool Plane::contains(Vector& point){
    return normalVector.dotProduct(point - position) < -doubleResolution;
}
```

When I compile it using g++ version 4.1.2 , I get the following error:

```
Plane.cpp: In member function âvirtual bool Plane::contains(Vector&)â:
Plane.cpp:36: error: no matching function for call to âVector::dotProduct(Vector)â
Vector.h:19: note: candidates are: double Vector::dotProduct(Vector&)
```

So as you can see, the compiler thinks (point-position) is a Vector but it's expecting Vector&.

What's the best way to fix this?

I verified that this works:

```
Vector temp = point-position;
return normalVector.dotProduct(temp) < -doubleResolution;
```

But I was hoping for something a little bit cleaner.

I heard a suggestion that adding a copy constructor might help. So I added a copy constructor to Vector (see below), but it didn't help.

Vector.h:

```
Vector(const Vector& other);
```

Vector.cpp:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& other)
    :x(other.x), y(other.y), z(other.z), homogenous(other.homogenous) {
}
```

Comment: Concerning the "works in Visual Studio" issue, Visual C++ has a language extension that allows binding of a temporary to a non-const reference.  You can disable the language extensions in the project properties, and it's probably a good idea to do so if you want to write portable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the result of `point - position` is a temporary object, which cannot be bound to a non-const reference.

If a function does not modify an argument taken by reference, then it should take a const reference.  Ergo,  your dot product function should be declared as:

```
double Vector::dotProduct(const Vector&);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. Thanks to everyone else who suggested a similar answer too.

Answer (score 2):

A `Vector` temporary variable can't properly be converted to a `Vector&` -- I guess MSVC++ is being too lax here.  Why do `contains` and `dotProduct` take a `Vector&` where they never really need to *modify* the arg?!  They should take a `const Vector&`!  I think gcc is guiding you correctly here.

Comment: I believe VC++ will issue a warning about it, but it will still let it compile, so yes, it's a bit more lax.

Answer (score 1):

`point - position` seems to creates temporary object of type `Vector` and you are trying to pass temporary to a function that requires reference. It is not allowed. Try declare it as `dotProduct(const Vector&);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your dotProduct function should take its parameter by const reference.

Comment: The other vector is the implicit parameter (this).

Comment: @Matthew, right... wasn't thinking. For some reason I didn't see the "normalVector." before the invocation.